# optionsCaption displaying on edit instead of selected value

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5, typescript

I have a select box that has three values.  I would like to add text that says "Please Select" when there is no selectedPhoneType value.

I tried adding `optionsCaption: 'Please Select'` to the data-bind attribute.

The problem is that when I do this and click edit on the page the PhoneType select reverts from the selected phone type to the 'Please Select' text instead of displaying the correct value.  When I remove the optionsCaption it displays the correct value on the edit page.

How can I get it to stop displaying 'Please Select' when there is a value for selectedPhoneType that should be displayed instead?

```
        <select id="PhoneType" data-bind="options: $root.phoneTypes, optionsText: 'phoneTypeDescription', optionsValue: 'phoneTypeId',  value: $root.selectedPhoneType, disable: phoneId() > 0" required></select>
```

view model

```
module ViewModels {
    export class Phone {
        constructor() {
            // Set up validation options
            ko.validation.init({
                insertMessages: false,
                decorateElement: true,
                errorElementClass: "input-validation-error"
            });

            var service = new Services.PhoneService();

            Q.all([
                service.getByFid()
                .then((phones: Array<Models.Phone>) => {
                    this.phones(phones);
                })
            ]).then(() => {
                // Populate drop downs based on static data
                var phoneTypes = Enums.PhoneTypeHelper.createArray();
                this.phoneTypes(phoneTypes);

                // This will diplay grid once the results have returned
                $("#sub-content").css("display", "block");
            }).fail((error: any) => {
                // Add this error to errors
                this.errors([error]);
            }).fin(() => {
                $("#loading").css("display", "none");
            });
        }

        phones = ko.observableArray<Models.Phone>();
        phoneTypes = ko.observableArray<Models.PhoneTypeLookup>();
        selectedPhoneType = ko.observable<number>().extend({ required: { message: "Please select a phone type." } });
        selectedPhone = ko.observable<Models.Phone>();
        template = ko.observable<string>("mainTemplate");
        errors = ko.observableArray<string>();

        // Used to handle the click event for Edit
        edit = (phone: Models.Phone) => {
            var phoneTypes = Enums.PhoneTypeHelper.createArrayWith(phone.phoneTypeId());

            this.phoneTypes(phoneTypes);
            this.selectedPhone(phone);
            this.template("editTemplate");

            // Add input masks
            $("#PhoneNumber").mask("999-999-9999", { placeholder: "###-###-####" });
            $("#PhoneExtension").mask("9999", { placeholder: "####" });
        }
```

Comment: Why do you change only the `phoneTypes` and not the `selectedPhoneType ` in the edit method? However you can try to "fix" your problem with adding also the `valueAllowUnset: true` property to your binding. But this does not solve the original problem that your `selectedPhoneType` is lost when you call your `edit` function

Comment: I don't know, this is some code I inherited.  Maybe i need to set the selectedPhoneType in the edit method.  It selects the right one automatically when i don't have the optionsCaption attribute set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to the edit section and it worked.  Thanks for the suggestion nemesv.

```
this.selectedPhoneType(phone.phoneTypeId());
```